# Counting the number of elements in a List and appending it to the end of each item and maintaining insertion order in list to be returned?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, hashmap

I am working on a problem and needed some possible approaches to it.

Sample input:

```
["tv", "speaker", "tv", "radio", "radio", "tv"]
```

Sample output:

```
["tv", "speaker", "tv1", "radio", "radio1", "tv2"]
```

Add the number of occurrences while leaving the first occurrence as it is.

So far I have added the elements to a HashMap and using Collection.frequency/get put for the element count to count the number of elements. However, what would be a way to append the corresponding number at the end?

```
public class DeviceManagement {
    public static List<String> Solution(List<String> ls) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        int counter = 1;

        for (String str : ls) {
            if (map.containsKey(str)) {
                map.put(str, map.get(str) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(str, counter);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(map);
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
        ls.add("speaker");
        ls.add("tv");
        ls.add("radio");
        ls.add("toaster");
        ls.add("radio");
        ls.add("speaker");
        System.out.println(ls);
        System.out.println(Solution(ls));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Map<String, Integer>` to keep track of how many of each distinct item you've seen; then iterate over the input list, modify the item name according to the information you've stored in the Map, add the modified name to the result, and adjust the Map to record one more occurrence of that item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code correctly detects duplicates and counts frequencies, but doesn't replace any elements in the `List` with their new values while you're iterating over it. To make this easy, I recommend using [`List#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) instead of a for-loop. Your code would look something like:

```
public static List<String> solution(List<String> ls) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    ls.replaceAll(element -> {
        if (map.containsKey(element)) {
            int oldAmount = map.put(element, map.get(element) + 1);
            return element + oldAmount;
        } else {
            map.put(element, 1);
            return element;
        }
    });

    return ls;
}
```

This would result in your output being:

```
[speaker, tv, radio, toaster, radio1, speaker1]
```

---

To simplify your code a bit, you can utilize [`Map#merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```
public static List<String> solution(List<String> ls) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    ls.replaceAll(element -> {
        int newValue = map.merge(element, 1, Integer::sum);
        return newValue == 1 ? element : element + (newValue - 1);
    });

    return ls;
}
```

---

If you want to return a different `List` object, then you can stream your input, map it, and collect it to another `List`:

```
public static List<String> solution(List<String> ls) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    return ls.stream().map(element -> {
        int newValue = map.merge(element, 1, Integer::sum);
        return newValue == 1 ? element : element + (newValue - 1);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you for the explanation. I did not know I could use replace all. Great solution